# Rails form testing: post directly or through form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, ruby-on-rails-5

Most examples of Rails tests I have seen post directly to a url. I found out recently that Rails supports the manipulation of form elements using 'fill_in' and 'click_on'.

**Should I be posting directly or submitting through the forms manually?** Filling in the forms manually seems much more thorough, and the reason I ask is, well, all the examples I've seen are posting directly. Obviously there may be a little less work with posting directly, but I'm curious what cases I might be missing. Is there a best practice?

Answer (score 2):

You have different levels of testing, that have their tradeoffs.  What you are describing is what could be called an integration test with the browser, they have these characteristics

- Very black boxy, so you perform a series of steps (Login, fill in some elements, click submit) and assert affects (that displays a message on the screen that it has been created and you see some proof of that).
- These tests are normally associated with being slower and less reliable (false alerts) but give you a very high degree of certainty that something actually works between multiple systems (rails app server, javascript in browser, database, caching, other services)

That is contrasted with Unit testing which is more asserting that one little piece of your system works.  Like some method on a class works properly.  In your example, that could be asserting that your model is able to accept some set attributes and save.  This allows you to isolate your dependencies through mocking/stubbing.  These are normally faster and more reliable but they give you less certainty that everything works as expected.

There are a few variables, but normally unless it is a crazy high value form I will normally just test the model validations and any form objects that are called with specific arguments that could cause issues.